# Преобразование массива Object к параметризованному типу

Tags: java, generics, типы-данных

Известно, что в Java дженерики реализованы на основе модели стирания типов, то есть если имеется класс

```
class CatContainer <T>{
    T[] names;
    public CatContainer(){
        names=(T[]) new Object[10];
    }
}
```

То на этапе выполнения программа заменяет параметризованный тип на тип `Object`, то есть программа не имеет информации о реальном типе параметра `T`.

Отсюда вопрос, если создать объект контейнера следующим образом:

```
CatContainer<String> cats=new CatContainer<>();
```

Почему при данной операции

```
cats.names[0]=5;
```

возникает ошибка?

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String

Я полагаю, что в данном случае происходит предварительная (compile time) проверка корректности программы, в процессе которой используются другие механизмы защиты, нежели при проверке корректности программы на этапе выполнения (run time). Но четкого понимания того, как это происходит у меня нет

Comment: А какая ошибка? Напишите в вопросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все верно, в рантайме информация о дженериках стирается. Но в вашем вопросе речь идет об ошибке компиляции. Компилятор достаточно сообразителен, чтобы вывести тип массива и проверить его с типом объекта который присваивается

Answer (score 0):

Потому что `5` это литерал типа `int`, который является примитивом. Примитивы могут автоматически бокситься в соответствующие объекты, в данном случае в `Integer`. Но `Integer` не кастится в `String`, который вы тут используете при объявлении `cats`. Замените `String` на `Integer`, `Number` или даже `Object` и у вас всё скомпилируется, потому что `Integer` кастится в любой из этих трёх.

Кстати, дженерики в Java реализованы не на основе стирания типа, а на основе правил безопасного кастинка. Стирание типа - лишь побочный эффект.